# How do I forbid search engine to index subdirectory /CRM with robot.txt?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

Or even forbid indexing the whole site?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) file and add the appropriate `Disallow` directives, such as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /CRM
```

Comment: How to write the `Disallow` s?

Comment: So I can use `Disallow: /` to forbidden indexing the whole site,right?

Comment: Keep in mind that the robots.txt is case-sensitive, so if the folder is called /crm, you need to "disallow: /crm". If the server is not case-sensitive, you may need to disallow multiple versions of the path.